# Access all Laravel routes in Vue template

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, routes

I'm basically trying to create some sort of a dynamic table using Vue in Laravel.
I have created the table successfully and grabbing data via jquery's `$.getJSON` method. I really want to have a link inside the table which would point to a URL by using Laravel's `route()` method as I have many different routes that i would like to use.

Example in this case is that the table contains a list of all users, and I would like to have a view user link on each user. But i cannot access Laravel's `route()` inside of a Vue component.

To make this a very short question: Is there any way to access all the routes Laravel has besides adding a single route to the attributes field on the template like so:

```
<user-table-component dataRoute="{{ route('datatable.users') }}">
</user-table-component>
```

I am open for suggestions as to how I go forth about fixing this another way.
Also, here is the template:

```
<template>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td v-for="header in json.headers" :key="header">{{ header }}</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="user in json.rows.data" :key="user">
                <td><a href="THIS WOULD BE AN VIEW USER LINK">{{ user.name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.created_at }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</template>



<script>
    module.exports = {
        name: 'user-table-component',
        props: ['dataroute'],

        data: function(){
            return {
                json: []
            }
        },

        // This is auto-run when the Vue app is booted up
        mounted() {

            // Closure to accept component in the callback below
            var self = this;
            $.getJSON(this.dataroute, function(json) {
                self.json = json;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
https://github.com/tighten/ziggy
```

Then in Javascript you can use `route('route.name')`

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why i couldn't find that in the first place. Thanks again!